# Show data downloaded with Parse in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, android-viewpager

I have followed the developers tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) to build ViewPager swipe view into my app and it works fine, displays test data that I put into an array.

However, my app downloads data from parse (images and text which also works fine), but I can not get the downloaded images to be displayed in the View pager allowing the user to swipe through them.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glide, it's a loading & caching library :
[Glide library on GitHub](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

easy usage :

```
Glide.with(this).load("http://yourURL.com/image").into(imageView);
```